# Regex is not including spaces

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm using some atwho.js to allow linking to users profile using @.

For example @User1 @User2 @User3, and all these would link to their profile.

I'm getting correct feedback from regexr.com, but it isn't translating,

and it's not including the space

Here is what my record displays in the database displays:

```
<p><a href=/profiles/Richard Skiles>@Richard Skiles</a></p>
```

Here is what the output is:

```
<p><a href=/profiles/Richard>@Richard Skiles</a></p>
```

Here is some code:

```
public function setBodyAttribute($body)
{
    $find = ['/@([\w\- ]+)/'];
    $replace = ['<a href=/profiles/$1>$0</a>'];
    $this->attributes['body'] = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me here. It would be much appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried replacing the space with "%20" or having the URL part in quotation marks? (<p><a href="/profiles/Richard Skiles">@Richard Skiles</a></p>)

Answer (score 0):

I saw you added a space in the character set, but the `preg_replace` doesn't match spaces like that. They use the `\s` class

```
public function setBodyAttribute($body)
{
    $find = ['/@([\w\-\s]+)/']; // I added the \s to match the spaces
    $replace = ['<a href=/profiles/$1>$0</a>'];
    $this->attributes['body'] = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
}
```

Comment: Hello. I did try this. However it did not work. Thank you.

Comment: Could you update your question with the `$body`